# How to compute a value on demand and cache this value in FP/F#?

Tags: .net, functional-programming, f#

In C# (OOP) I can easily compute a value on demand and remember the value once computed (aka caching), e.g.

```cs
    class WorkItem {
        private Dictionary<string, object> myFields;
        private WorkItemState myState;
        // ...
        public WorkItemState State {
            get {
                if (myState == null) {
                    myState = ParseWorkItemState(myFields["State"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Alternatively I could also use `Lazy<T>`.

I could simulate the same OOP style approach in F# using classes and mutable fields or
probably again the "lazy" expression but what would be a more "idiomatic FP" approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: *The same as in C#*.

## State

In Functional Programming (FP), you can always use the [State Monad](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/06/20/the-state-monad) to 'simulate ' state mutation, so one option is to pass state around:

```
let doSomething myFields myState =
    match myState with
    | Some s -> "foo", s
    | None -> "bar", parseWorkItemState (myFields["State"])
```

While 'functional', one may argue whether this is really necessary.

## Referential transparency

If we assume that the state you want to [memoise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is immutable and that the function that calculates it is [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency), whether or not you memoise the value in a mutable field is of less importance.

This is, ultimately, a semi-philosophical question of what FP really is. In [my view](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/11/19/functional-architecture-a-definition), it's about referential transparency. If you memoise a referentially transparent function with a mutable field, it remains referentially transparent.

## Lazy

If you buy that argument, then, you can often use `lazy` computations in F#, just as you do in C#. The requirement, however, is that the memoised function is referentially transparent.

If it's not, then [nothing you do will be functional](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/27/from-dependency-injection-to-dependency-rejection).

---

Based on comments, I present the following variation of [this original memoisation snippet](http://www.fssnip.net/mW/title/memoize-):

```
let memoize (dict : System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<_, _>) fn x =
    match dict.TryGetValue x with
    | true, v -> v
    | false, _ ->
        let v = fn (x)
        dict.Add(x,v)
        v
```

Instead of using a 'global' dictionary to store memoised values, it closes over a passed-in dictionary. One can create a memoised function by partially applying it:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let f = memoize (Dictionary<int, int> ()) (fun n -> n*n)
```

The memoised function `f` closes over the dictionary, which goes out of scope and gets garbage-collected together with `f` itself.

You can pass `f` around, and the dictionary is along for the ride.

This fits conceptually nicely with the realisation that [closures are objects, and objects are closures](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/02/12/object-isomorphisms).

Comment: i think i understand your answer BUT doesn't that either result in passing a state around the code base OR, if i "statically" memoise the function, a global dictionary is needed to remember the results of the function per function input? In OOP the cached value would be freed once the object instance holding it got garbage collected but in FP the cache probably remains for ever, right? 
(having a s.th. like this in mind:
module Fun =
    let Memoize (fn:'a -> 'b) =
        let cache = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<'a,'b>()
        fun x -> cache.GetOrAdd(x, fn))

Comment: @plainionist There's no reason for global variables; you can't just close over a dictionary. Here's an example: http://www.fssnip.net/mW/title/memoize-

Comment: that's basically the same what i included in my comment above - ok it is not truly global, it is a closure but it's effectively the same: "globally" shared for functions created with this memoize call. AND: this dictionary never get's cleared. 
anyhow, thx - then i accept (for now) that there is no more elegant version

Comment: @plainionist Last I checked, F#/C# closures get compiled to auto-generated classes, so once the function goes out of scope, it should get garbage-collected, just like other objects.

Comment: certainly still true - i just had no local function in mind but a "global" one defined in a "global" module - hence I thought of global scoped state

Comment: @plainionist Yes, but for memoisation to be effective, wouldn't you do the same with the C# `WorkItem` object you sketch in the OP?

Comment: @MarkSeemannn in OOP i would put the cache inside the WorkItem object so the cache remains as long as the instance of a particular WorkItem lives. In FP i can only think of a) local function (within some other function) which invalidates the cache once the local function leaves scope OR a global function in a global module which keeps state forever (until process dies) - i dont see any option to couple the lifetime of the cache to the instance of e.g. a WorkItem record in FP

Comment: @plainionist I've updated my answer.

Comment: thx! I think this is an interesting approach - i ll give it a try in my context

Comment: Given that memoize operates on a Dictionary and not a ConcurrentDictionary, f is not thread safe. Probably worth a disclaimer in the example.